# Regex for exclude characters and find a certan match

Tags: regex

I have to extract -(4)- from a log and have to use regex.
my code is

```
regex /(?!-)\d{1}+(?=-)/
```

and input is

```
ASA-5510-6 : %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src INTERNET:TEJ-BHARTI-ILL-2Mbps-
```

But with this regex it is also extracting similar other pattern  (-5510-). I just want this(4) specfic four to be extracted.

and the whole log is

```
2011-12-01T00:02:04.382593+05:18 Dec 01 2011 00:00:29 KOC-TEJ-AMEX-ASA-5510-6 : %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src INTERNET:TEJ-BHARTI-ILL-2Mbps-ROUTER-LAN-IP/58653 dst TCS:VIS-SYSLOG-SERVER/514 by access-group "INTERNET_access_in" [0xc97c8100, 0x0]
```

Thanks

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: What?  If you need "-4-", well, use "-4".  If there's something about the pattern (like it's preceded by "%ASA" or it's only a single digit), you have to say so.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  What differentiates the second -N- from the other?  Is it the %ASA?  Is it the 4?  Are you just looking for the Nth occurrence?

Comment: I am using IBM AQL Text Analytics.

Comment: Its is a pattern it is preceded always by %ASA . And i want to cature the "4" not "-4-".

Comment: if you using linux OS you can easy get selected logs by trail command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the %ASA in the lookbehind.  Also the `{1}` is redundant, and the `+` matches more than one 4.

`/(?<=%ASA-)4(?=-)/g` If you just want to match a 4.

`/(?<=%ASA-)\d+(?=-)/g` If you want to match any group of digits.

(I was unsure if you wanted to just match a four or anything where the 4 was in the input example)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

/%ASA-(\d+)-/

It looks like you're trying to match the number after "%ASA-" in the log.

You don't need the {1} after \d since you are using +. {1} means you only one 1 digit, whereas + means you want multiple digits. {1}+ would mean you want multiple 1 digits, which is the same as just multiple digits.

According to [the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/bigins/v1r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.text.doc/doc/biginsights_aqlref_ref_regular-expressions.html) you can return match groups (the things in parenthesis) with this syntax:

```
create view Phone as
extract regex /(\d{3})-(\d{3}-\d{4})/ 
    on between 4 and 5 tokens in D.text 
    return 
        group 1 as areaCode
        and group 2 as restOfNumber
        and group 0 as fullNumber
from Document D;
```

Group 0 is the full match, so what you want is group 1, which is the first parenthesized capture group. Tacking "return group 1 as someNumber" on the end of your query should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `lookaheads`, JavaScript doesn't support Regex `lookbehind` syntax. See these postes:

- [Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)
- [JavaScript Regex Lookbehind Redux](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind)